# Phonegap IOS - Plugin Push Setup

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, push-notification

I'm developing an App using Phonegap and Phonegap Build. The app has been pretty much completed but I'm not working on the Push Notifications.

I'm struggling to get a device to even be registered at all. I've added the following plugin to my project (added in the config for phonegap build) https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

I added the plugin and have following in my javascript file.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "1234567890"
            },
            "ios": { "alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true" },
            "windows": {}
        });

        push.on('registration', function (data) {
            console.log("registration event");
            //document.getElementById("regId").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
            alert(data.registrationId)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        push.on('notification', function (data) {
            console.log("notification event");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            var cards = document.getElementById("cards");
            var card = '<div class="row">' +
                  '<div class="col s12 m6">' +
                  '  <div class="card darken-1">' +
                  '    <div class="card-content black-text">' +
                  '      <span class="card-title black-text">' + data.title + '</span>' +
                  '      <p>' + data.message + '</p>' +
                  '    </div>' +
                  '  </div>' +
                  ' </div>' +
                  '</div>';
            cards.innerHTML += card;

            push.finish(function () {
                console.log('finish successfully called');
            });
        });

        push.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("push error");
        });

    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

function successHandler(result) {
    alert('result = ' + result); //Here you will get your device id.
}


function errorHandler(error) {
    alert('error = ' + error);
}
```

So, I'm not sure where to go from here exactly. I've set up an account with push wizard and have created the additional certificates, but that is not picking up any devices as I assume there is no devices that are set to receive notifications yet.

So I guess my main issue is, am I missing something stupid like a registration stage, where my device is registered to receive notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `this` context correctly. This is a common mistake. The Javascript `this` does NOT work like the Java `this`.

The reason it does not work is because the `this` gets resolved at **run-time**, not *assemble-time* (or *compile-time*). When the event fires, `this` resolves to the the global `this` because your `app` object is now out of scope. The event fires *outside* of your `app` object.

A quick fix would be to do `app.onDeviceReady` instead of <s>`this.onDeviceReady`</s>  You can test this by making your`onDeviceReady()` a global function and leaving the `this` in place.

These videos should help. – Best of Luck.

- [Context in JavaScript - 1/4 - Purpose and Problems with JavaScript's "This"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=su-SdgebJCE)
- [Context in JavaScript - 2/4 - How JavaScript Decides What "This" Actually Is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJ_YD4Ljbqc)
- [Context in JavaScript - 3/4 - "This" May Not Be What You Expected & How to Fix It](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNqoehDEZ3E)
- [Context in JavaScript - 4/4 - Mastering "This:" Additional Techniques & Future Support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QQ4__W9nELc)

Comment: Thank you, That would explain why this section wasn't being picked up at all! Also, there was another section I missed out, which i have linked in my section.

Answer (score 0):

So there was 2 sections to this, First what jesseMonroy mentioned, my code wasn't being picked up properly and my js file wasn't being run properly.

The second part was that I wasn't calling a register function, which allows you to get a device_token.

```
        push.registerDevice({ alert: true, badge: true, sound: true }, function (status) {
            app.myLog.value += JSON.stringify(['registerDevice status: ', status]) + "\n";
            app.storeToken(status.deviceToken);
            alert(status.deviceToken)
        });
```

This is what i was missing. my whole init section looks like this;

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "1234567890"
            },
            "ios": { "alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true" },
            "windows": {}
        });

        push.on('registration', function (data) {
            console.log("registration event");
            //document.getElementById("regId").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
            alert(data.registrationId)
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        });

        push.on('notification', function (data) {
            console.log("notification event");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            var cards = document.getElementById("cards");
            var card = '<div class="row">' +
                  '<div class="col s12 m6">' +
                  '  <div class="card darken-1">' +
                  '    <div class="card-content black-text">' +
                  '      <span class="card-title black-text">' + data.title + '</span>' +
                  '      <p>' + data.message + '</p>' +
                  '    </div>' +
                  '  </div>' +
                  ' </div>' +
                  '</div>';
            cards.innerHTML += card;

            push.finish(function () {
                console.log('finish successfully called');
            });
        });

        push.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log("push error");
        });


        //  var pushNotification = window.plugins.PushNotification;
        push.registerDevice({ alert: true, badge: true, sound: true }, function (status) {
            app.myLog.value += JSON.stringify(['registerDevice status: ', status]) + "\n";
            app.storeToken(status.deviceToken);
            alert(status.deviceToken)
        });
```