# Function not running on button click on phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, camera, phonegap-build

I have the following HTML:

```
...

</head>
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Match It!</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="camera">take a pic</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>

...
```

I am trying to make the camera open when the button with id `camera` is clicked.

I have the following JavaScript in index.js:

```
var app = {

    ...

    cameraUse: function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imagePath){
            document.getElementById("photoImg").setAttribute("src", imagePath);
        }, function(){
            alert("Photo cancelled");
        }, {
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });
    },

    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        document.getElementById("camera").addEventListener("click", cameraUse, false);
    },
```

I want the `cameraUse` function to execute when the button is clicked.

Comment: your above is wrong, change `document.getElementById("camera").addEventListener("click", cameraUse, false);` to `document.getElementById("camera").addEventListener("click", app.cameraUse, false);` You need to add **app.** before `cameraUse` SEE ALSO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778334/phonegap-ios-plugin-push-setup/33795945#33795945 - Javascript is not Java.

Answer (score 2):

Did you download the cordova camera [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera), if not download and try your code

use 
for cordova version 5.0+ 
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

for older versions
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera

Comment: cool ill check it out...for now im trying to get a google maps map to open up after i click a button...having trouble...wanna help?

Comment: Try this [https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

Comment: this is what i have been looking at...I am trying to make it so that a button opens the map...ill ask a new question and tag you

Answer (score 0):

Changed my javascript to this:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    document.getElementById("camera").addEventListener("click", function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imagePath){
            document.getElementById("photoImg").setAttribute("src", imagePath);
        }, function(){
            alert("Photo cancelled");
        }, {
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });
    }, false);
}
```

The difference lies in the fact that I moved the code responsible for opening the camera, directly into the `addEventListener` call, instead of having it in it's own function within the `app` variable.

Comment: It would be helpful for other people viewing this question in the future if you edit your answer and add an explanation on how this change solved your problem. Also remember to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. You can mark your own answer as accepted, for future reference, and [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) any answers that were helpful to you. Cheers.