# Overriding Android back button is being a challenge Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, listener, back-button

I am developing an Hybrid Mobile Application using JQuery Mobile wrapped by Cordova.

My Jquery version is 2.1.4 and Jquery Mobile version is 1.4.5. Similarly my Cordova CLI version is 5.3.3.

I need to override Android back button behaviour which kills the activity. So I used `backbutton` listener of Cordova. I am calling this event on `deviceready`. But still, on tap of Android back, the event i snot getting called and the App is getting killed.

My index.html is,

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/JQuery/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/JQuery/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>


    <!-- PAGE/APPLICATION STYLE SHEETS -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">

    <script src="libs/JQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/JQuery/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

    <title>Override Back</title>

</head>

<body>

<div id="page-index" data-role="page">


    <div role="main">

        <div class="ui-content"></div>

    </div>

</div>


</body>

</html>
```

And my index.js is ,

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {

        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false );

        app.OrganizationInformation();
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        /*var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
         var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
         var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

         listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
         receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

         console.log('Received Event: ' + id);*/

    }
};

app.initialize();
```

The plugin I am using are,

```
com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect 0.4.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 2.1.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.4.4 "PushPlugin"
```

Can anyone help me in understanding why this listener is not getting called. I followed many blogs and answers but couldn't succeed. Thanks for you help in Advance.

Comment: Your "deviceready" listener is called? If you don't know can you make an alert('deviceready') on onDeviceReady method?

Comment: Yes, Device ready got fired. I even did alert and it got called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Joseph,
You have three issues. One has less effect, but will one day catch up. The other issue, not being able to trap the `[backbutton]`, is simpler to see.

**On #1**, `e.preventDefault();` does not do anything. The event is NOT browser related and is not subjected to the usual "Event bubbling". See [Event Order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) – and [older post on subject](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/android_back_button_prevent_default_behavior_not_working#reply_16065609)

**On #2**, you need to wait until the `deviceready` event fires before you do ANYTHING. This includes calling other libraries.

As is stated in the documentation for the [`deviceready` event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) :

> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code loads, a custom loading image displays. However, JavaScript only loads once the DOM loads. This means the web app may potentially call a Cordova JavaScript function before the corresponding native code becomes available.
>
> The `deviceready` event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. Once the event fires, you can safely make calls to Cordova APIs. Applications typically attach an event listener with `document.addEventListener` once the HTML document's DOM has loaded.
>
> The `deviceready` event behaves somewhat differently from others. Any event handler registered after the `deviceready` event fires has its callback function called immediately.

I highly urge you to reorganize your code.

**On #3**, there is a common mistake in your code. The `this` in your code, when the event is called, is out of scope. This means that the following code is not working:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
```

There are several ways to fix this.

1. Make the `onDeviceReady()` function global, because this is what your code is calling.
2. Make a direct call to the library, as if it was an external to the library.

Like this:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
},
```

To be clear, when the `this.onDeviceReady()` is finally made, it is "out of scope" and global.

For a more details explanation, read to following SO post:
[Phonegap IOS - Plugin Push Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778334/phonegap-ios-plugin-push-setup/33795945#33795945)

Best of Luck